# Filtering required from object from array of objects

Tags: javascript

My Structure of data will be like below

```
 var data = {"Questions" : [
                  {"QID":"Q1","S":"2"},
                  {"QID":"Q2","T":"12"},   
                  {"QID":"Q3","U":"22"}], // Also please suggest me to improve this to make parsing easier
             "Share" : "Yes"
            };
 for(var item in data.Questions)
 {
    if(this.QID == "Q2") // this.QID returns me undefined
    {
        // I want to retrieve the total object i.e
        // {"QID":"Q2","T":"12"} should be returned
    }
 }
```

Why does `this.QID` return me `undefined`?  How can I retrieve the total object, i.e. `{"QID":"Q2","T":"12"}`?

Comment: @minitech Read the Question please.. I have specified comments on what problems I am getting... I don't think I have written non-English characters above :-)

Comment: My point being: "What question?" You haven't specified anything. Your question makes little sense and you need to elaborate. Where does `this.QID` come from, for instance?

Comment: @minitech I thought there might be problem and I have specified comment to that line :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't iterate Arrays using `for .. in` loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261096/361684).  Use a regular `for` loop or [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)*.

That aside, `this` is *not* going to be an item in your Array.  You need:

```
if (data.Questions[item].QID == "Q2") {
    ...
}
```

Using a regular `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.Questions.length; i++) {   
    if (data.Questions[i].QID == "Q2") {   
        ...
    }    
}
```

Or, my preferred method, `Array.forEach()`:

```
data.Questions.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.QID == "Q2") {
        ...
    }
});
```

*Older browsers don't natively support `Array.forEach()`, but you can add it in yourself.  See the [compatibility notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility) for an implementation you can use in your code for older browsers.

Comment: Very thanks for your great support. This is what why I love stackoverflow.com :-)

Comment: I am gonna use forEach as my browser support this method. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Change your iteration code to this:

```
var questions = data.Questions;
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    if (questions[i].QID == "Q2") {
        // questions[i] is all the data of this array element
    } 
}
```

Arrays should NOT be iterated with `for (x in array)`.  That type of iteration iterates over object properties which will also pick up array elements, but it's not recommended.  Use array indexing or `.forEach()` in a modern browser to iterate through an array in a predictable order and without any other properties showing up in the iteration.

In addition, the way you were trying to do the iteration does not set `this` to anything so you can't use it to access the array element.